# Prove that if $G$ is a $p$-group, $p$ is prime, then $G'=[G,G] \subseteq Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

I have proved if $G$ is a $p$-group, $G$ is nilpotent, and the lower central series and the upper central series have a finite length and both cover from $G$ to/downto $\lbrace 1 \rbrace$. But I do not know how to prove $[G,G]\subseteq Z(G)$. Some hint?

Comment: The dihedral group of order $16$ is a counterexample, $|[G,G]|=4$, $|Z(G)|=2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde You're completely right. The first inequality in my comment is incorrect: it should be $\;\gamma_i\le \zeta _{n-i+1}\;$  (with $\;\zeta_i\;$ the inverse images of the central series terms), with $\;n=\;$ the nilpotency degree...and then $\;\gamma_2=[\gamma_1,G]=[G,G]\;$ and we get what I wrote in case the group is metabelian.. I shall delete to avoid confusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim of the title is not true in general, see here:

[Very generic question about Commutator and Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265605/very-generic-question-about-commutator-and-center)

Every group $G$ with $G'\subseteq Z(G)$ is $2$-step solvable, hence metabelian. Not every $p$-group is metabelian.

Comment: The assertion in the title of the question is proved in the book of Marshall Hall, and is general for all nilpotent finite groups .

Comment: The assertion in the title of the question is proved in the book of Marshall Hall, and is general for all nilpotent finite groups . He prove that if $D\equiv G\supset G^{(1)}\supset\ldots$ and we have an ascendent $A\equiv \{1\}\subset Z(G)\equiv Z^{(2)}(G)\subset\ldots$, then $G^{i}\subset Z^{c+1-i}(G)$.

Comment: I repeat by errors. The assertion in the title of the question is proved in the book of Marshall Hall, and is general for all nilpotent finite groups . He prove that if $D\equiv G\supset G^{(1)}\supset\ldots$ and we have an ascendent $A\equiv \{1\}\subset Z(G)\subset Z_{(2)}(G)\subset\ldots$, then $G^{i}\subset Z_{c+1-i}(G)$.

Comment: @EärendilElrondArwen How do you explain then the counterexample, namely the group $D_8$ of order $16$, which is a $p$-group with $G'$ not contained in the center $Z(G)$?

Comment: But, where is the error in my interpretation of the result in the book of M. Hall?